# PiracyChecker fails to check whether the app is installed from Google Play Store

Tags: android, google-play, android-library, piracy

I'm using '[com.github.javiersantos:PiracyChecker:1.2.3](https://github.com/javiersantos/PiracyChecker)' because my app is not yet integrates AndroidX.

I have numerous reports from user reviews in my app's Google Play page that **they have installed the app from the Google Play Store, yet they getting the piracy warning message.**

Here are some examples:

[image]

**Also got a user report via email:**

[image]

My app have 4k reviews and only 3 of them are like this, but **I don't know the exact user count because there could be users who don't comment about this issue.**

What is going on?

I use it like this:

```
    public static void showPiracyActivityIfNeeded(final Activity activity) {
    if (!BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
        //Releaseb build, piracy check.
        new PiracyChecker(activity)
                .enableInstallerId(InstallerID.GOOGLE_PLAY)
                .callback(new PiracyCheckerCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void allow() {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void dontAllow(@NonNull PiracyCheckerError piracyCheckerError, @Nullable PirateApp pirateApp) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(activity, PiracyWarningActivity.class);
                        activity.startActivity(intent);
                        activity.finish();
                    }
                })
                .start();
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: According to author of library: "This seems to happen when the device has just booted. ..PiracyChecker checks before Google Play Services has actually started."

Comment: If the issue is that the Google Play Services haven't started. Could you do the piracy check on a background thread, and then if it triggers the don't allow, check again in a minute or so just to make sure that the issue was just the Google Play Services not being started?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that your Google Play Services are unavailable. Try to check it before start your `PiracyActivity`:

```
const val PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 9000

fun AppCompatActivity.checkPlayServices(): Boolean {
    val apiAvailability = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance()
    val resultCode = apiAvailability.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this)
    if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
        if (apiAvailability.isUserResolvableError(resultCode)) {
            apiAvailability.getErrorDialog(this, resultCode, PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST)
                .show()
        }
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```

And then:

```
public static void showPiracyActivityIfNeeded(final Activity activity) {
    if (!BuildConfig.DEBUG && activity.checkPlayServices()) { ...
```

Also note, there are a lot of devices that has Google Play Services turned off because of various reasons, so check availability of Services every time you need it.

Comment: Does this also affect if trying with manual check `context.packageManager.getInstallerPackageName(context.packageName)` Any suggestion ?